# When and how to use "to be"?

Tags: infinitives, to-infinitive

- For each tuft **to be** inserted along the width of the axminster carpet, there is a corresponding metal gripper which rises from the bed of the loom to grip the appropriate coloured end of yarn from the vertical yarn carrier.

This sentence has been taken from [this link.](http://www.brintons.co.uk/axminster-construction/)

Please, say details about the uses of **to be**. I don't know the way of using **to be** in the way it has been used in above sentence. What does **to be** mean in this sentence?

Answer (score 1):

It means "which someone will soon insert, or is expected to insert in the nearest future".

Or, if you prefer, "slated for insertion."

Happy hunting.